Failed to prune sessions: no pg_hba.conf entry for host, although connection works fine
I am using an AWS RDS Postgres database and Typeorm to connect to the database. I have also configured the RDS database to require a SSL connection. I pass the CA certificate to the database like this:
type: 'postgres',
          host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
          port: configService.get('DB_PORT'),
          username: configService.get('DB_USER'),
          password: configService.get('DB_PASS'),
          database: configService.get('DB_NAME'),
          synchronize: configService.get('TYPEORM_SYNC_DB'),
          autoLoadEntities: true,
          migrations: [
            path.join(__dirname, '..', 'migrations', '*-migration.js'),
          ],
          migrationsRun: configService.get('RUN_MIGRATIONS'),
          ssl: {
            ca: cert,
          },

My client code successfully connects to the database, and I am able to perform queries normally, however, after connecting, I do receive this error:
Failed to prune sessions: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "<host>", user "postgres", database "test", SSL off
I was not able to find any explanation online about this.
I have tried to use node-postgres directly to connect and have not received this error.
Would someone know why the error is there? Could it be a problem with the typeorm library?
I am really curious what is the cause and what I can do.
Thank you!

It seems to be a problem with your connection pooler, but I don't understand what connection pooler would even be in use in this situation.  From the database perspective, something tried to create a new connection.  Why your pooler would be trying to create connection when it thinks it is trying to prune one, I have no idea.
